# Is it legal to forge a employee's signautre

Tags: employment, forgery

I have recently been fired from my company. Filling out my unemployment information, I realized that my employer signed my W-4, and Direct Deposit Authorization as me (Forged). I am worried they may have done this with other forms I am not aware of. What can I do?

Comment: File a police report? If they signed your name on a government form (and weren't allowed to) then it's fraud or perjury or who knows what. The police will know or find out if a law was broken and pursue the matter if it's worth pursuing.

Comment: File a police report.

Comment: File a police report and complain to the IRS and FBI since this is also a federal crime.

Comment: I think "fraud" requires doing something that is damaging to you; I don't know whether them signing these forms (if it went undetected) would cause you damage.